# How to solve complex resistor combinations like the one given?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Question]
What is the equivalent resistance between A and B?

I tried to spot which resistors are connected in parallel and which in series but I just couldn't reform the combination into a solvable one.
So, I tried solving this using Kirchoff's current law:
[image: possible solution]

Equation 1: I1 + I2 = I

Equation 2: I3 + I4 = I1

Equation 3: I2 + I3 = I5

Equation 4: I4 + I5 = I

Solving eq 1 and 2, we get 
Equation 5: I3 + I4 + I2 = I

Solving eq 3 and 4, we get 
Equation 6: I4 + I2 + I3 = I

This obviously gets me nowhere either so I'm stumped. The teacher simply said they are all connected in parallel so the equivalent resistance is R/5. But I don't see how.

Comment: @Qmechanic Ok I read other discussion and realised it forms a wheatstone bridge. In that case, the answer would be R. So, my teacher was wrong. Thanks.